# Standard error in psych::describe function - what is it referring to?

Tags: r, psych, describe

Suppose we have a dataframe called "df", and we want to know the skewness and kurtosis values for a variable within df called "x".
Suppose we use:

```
psych::describe(df$x)
```

And get the following result:

```
  vars n  mean  sd median  trimmed mad   min max range  skew  kurtosis  se
1   1 478 98.54 19  102.5  100.57 18.53  34  125  91    -0.94   0.47    0.87
```

To what is the last value, the se, referring? The standard error of skew or kurtosis?

Comment: I can refer to followed documentation https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/psych/psych.pdf , page 95. There you can find all relevant information about the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`se` refers to the "standard error of the mean"

NB: you can read the source code typing `describe` in the R terminal.

In any case, as a double check, here it is the output of `describe` on the iris dataset

```
unlist(sapply(iris[1:4], describe)[13,])

#output
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
0.06761132   0.03558833   0.14413600   0.06223645
```

and here the output of a my handwritten function for the standard error of the mean

```
sapply(iris[1:4], sem)

#output
Sepal.Length  Sepal.Width Petal.Length  Petal.Width 
0.06761132   0.03558833   0.14413600   0.06223645
```

p.s. my `sem` function

```
function(x) {
    sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Do you know of any way to get skewness and kurtosis values, with their standard errors, for univariate distributions? All the functions I find seem to only provide the single value but no se.

Comment: Hi, there is the [rela](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rela/rela.pdf) library. From the linked manual: `Skewness, standard error of the skew, lower and upper values of the skew.`; and `Kurtosis, standard error of kurtosis as well as its respective 95 % confidence
interval values`. Alternatively, you can write your own functions following my `sem` example.

Comment: @WadeByronProfe, please, if your like the answer, you can accept it :)